# How can I use a third party CSS library in an Angular component's CSS without duplicating the library?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have a two components that both rely on effects from `hover.css`. Both components have SASS files that (simplified) look something like this:

```
@import '~hover.css/scss/hover';

.some-class a {
  @include underline-from-left;
}
```

Additionally, I have the `hover.css` library included in my global styles in `style.css`:

```
@import '~hover.css/scss/hover';

.some-global-class {
  @include some-other-mixin-from-hover;
}
```

This all works and compiles fine, except for the rather large fly in the ointment that I end up with full `hover.css` in my compiled application three times - once in `styles.js` and twice in `main.js` (once for each component). This is obviously not a sustainable pattern.

If I don't `@import` hover.css in my components though, Angular won't compile them because they reference a mixin that can't be found. I've tried deep linking just the effects I need from `hover.css` but that's a hornet's nest because those files have downstream dependencies on other parts of the hover library. This obviously isn't specific to hover, but any scenario in which you'd want to import and use a vendor library in an Angular component's CSS file without duplicating the library.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you have on your `hover.scss` file? Is it only mixins or other CSS as well? If you only have mixins then you should be fine, if you have some CSS then it will get taken. For example:

This would not cause repetition:

```
@mixin underline-from-left {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you have something like this, then the `span` block will be repeated as many times as you would import it:

```
@mixin underline-from-left {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
    display: block;
}
```

Perhaps an idea is to separate mixins from actual CSS, and then import only the mixins file.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, hover.css isn't my file, it's a third party library from https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ - it's just named hover.css. I have no control over the separation of CSS and mixins - and yeah, I get that's where the problem ultimately comes from. It;s a pretty big file because it's full of CSS.

Comment: After posting this question I spent ages looking for a solution and gave up. There's lots of talk about import-once techniques but none that I could get working in Angular's CLI wrapping around webpack, and it's rumoured to be planned for SASS v4 but that seems to have been in gestation for years. I actually depend quite lightly on this library so for now I've just cheery picked the mixins I need into my own SASS file. It's far from ideal because I'm version locked now but at least my bundle size is down.